# System.AccessViolationException : .NET Runtime Error : w3wp.exe Application

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, iis-7, windows-server-2012

I have been reported regarding some errors in my application's data consistency from last few days. When I checked the event logs on Application Server, I observed following error happening intermittently -

```
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException

Stack Trace
    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader..ctor(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, IntPtr[], IntPtr, IntPtr, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpoSqlValCtx*, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpoDacValCtx*, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.MetaData, Int32, System.Data.CommandBehavior, System.Collections.Hashtable, System.String, Int32)
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean, Boolean, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
       at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
       at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at Commons.DAL.AbstractDataAccessLayer`3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Select(System.Data.Common.DbCommand, System.Object[])
       at Commons.DAL.AbstractDataAccessLayer`3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Select(System.Data.Common.DbCommand)
       at Commons.DAL.AbstractDataAccessLayer`3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Select(System.__Canon)
       at BPL.Server.CoreModel.BpVisit.Get(EL.Server.CoreModel.EntityKeys.VisitKey, Boolean)
       at BPL.Server.CoreModel.BpVisit.UpdateVisit(EL.Server.CoreModel.Visit, System.String, System.String)
       at WebService.VisitsWCFService.UpdateModifiedVisitByTechRefact1(EL.Server.CoreModel.MTEnvironment, EL.Server.CoreModel.Visit)
       at WebService.VisitsWCFService.UpdateModifiedCompressedVisitByTechVersionned(EL.Server.CoreModel.MTEnvironment, Byte[])
       at DynamicClass.SyncInvokeUpdateModifiedCompressedVisitByTechVersionned(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[] ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc ByRef)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, Boolean, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext, System.ServiceModel.OperationContext)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)
       at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1+AsyncQueueReader[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Set(Item<System.__Canon>)
       at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnqueueAndDispatch(Item<System.__Canon>, Boolean)
       at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].EnqueueAndDispatch(System.__Canon, System.Action, Boolean)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Enqueue(System.__Canon, System.Action, Boolean)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline+EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline+EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.AsyncCompletionWrapperCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean)
       at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean, System.Exception)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput+ParseMessageAsyncResult.OnRead(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.Runtime.Fx+AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(System.IAsyncResult)
       at System.IO.Stream+ReadWriteTask.InvokeAsyncCallback(System.Object)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
       at System.IO.Stream+ReadWriteTask.System.Threading.Tasks.ITaskCompletionAction.Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

The application is running on the Windows Server 2012 64 Bit / Moreover, I am deploying my application in Release/x86 mode through Visual Studio 2010.

The version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll used is 2.102.2.20

Could someone please suggest what should be done in order to resolve this error?

Thanks.